# Memory leaks in windows service, IIS process doesn't die

Tags: c#, windows, service, httpclient

I'm currently working on a health monitoring service that will make a call to every website hosted by the current machine. What it does is a basic for that runs through all websites hosted, makes a call to the machine through HttpClient to every single one and saves their current status response to a database. The problem with this is that this service, when running, creates multiple IIS Worker Processes that simply don't disappear, and memory usage increases by 1% every few minutes. I'm pretty sure this is no coincidence, I've searched many different topics in regards to this issue but couldn't find a result that'd work for me.Any ideas on how to solve this issue? Here's an excerpt of the code I'm using:

```
        public void PingWebsites(List<Website> websites)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < websites.Count(); i++)
            {
                {

                    if (!websites[i].Environment.Contains("CI"))
                    {
                        Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = null;
                        try
                        {
                            response =  client.GetAsync(websites[i].Address);

                            if (!response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                            {
                                SaveStatus(websites[i].ID, 0);

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                SaveStatus(websites[i].ID, 1);
                            }

                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            SaveStatus(websites[i].ID, 0);
                        }
                        finally {
                            if (response != null)
                            {
                                response.Dispose();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I've also searched for the possibility of the timer being at fault and the sql invocation, but I believe this is more of an issue with the HttpClient.

EDIT: I've also tried using a unique instance of HttpClient but memory consumption was the same, with more and more being consumed over time, so that's not my current issue.

Comment: don't init httpclient in using block. see https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: The proper usage of `HttpClient` implies sharing a single instance rather than re-creating it each time you can read about this [here](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/). As for the multiple IIS worker process I presume they are related to the sites you're requesting if they were idling before.

Comment: @Daniel I've tried that method before yet it still caused the memory leaks, I've felt no difference so I eventually reverted to the original code. The problem persists all the same with increases of 1% usage per minute and IIS Worker Processes not disappearing, so I'm left to assume there's yet another issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out what was causing the issue, the requests would overload the machine with hundreds of requests and due shortage of memory, it would go crazy. After increasing its capacity, it no longer has this problem